# how to display data by passing value from php?

Tags: php, mysql

> Invalid SQL statement. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.A Biography of the Rev. Absalom Dawe.'' ORDER BY nmc_cd.CDTitle' at line 5

```
$CDTitle = $_REQUEST['CDTitle']; // make sure its only an id (SQL Incjection problems)
    $sql = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc, nmc_publisher.pubName
FROM nmc_cd
NATURAL JOIN nmc_category
NATURAL JOIN nmc_publisher
WHERE nmc_cd.CDTitle = '$CDTitle'
ORDER BY nmc_cd.CDTitle
LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem is currently

Comment: What is $CDTitle value?
Can you, please, output the final query, with  $CDTitle inserted?

Comment: It looks like the injection of `$CDTitle` is corrupting the syntax of his SQL statement.

Comment: No necessarily an injection. ' is enough to break it.
But you're right, there's SQLinjection vulnerability here

Comment: currently i wanted to display a full detail of cd in another page. whereby clicking on CDTitle will direct me to another page n displaying all cd details to me. examplae CDTitle, CDYear, CDPrice....

Comment: are you trying to submit text which has an (') apostrophe inside it?

Comment: yes i trying to submit text which has an (') apostrophe inside it

Comment: then remove it and try again

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `$CDTitle` has an `'` in it, which is throwing a wrench in the works.

At the very least you should run `$CDTitle` through [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). This will help against SQL injection attacks (as well as protect against these more mundane errors).

However, it is strongly recommended to use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements, as they are substantially more reliable.

Just to clarify, the simple way to fix it is to simply replace your first line with:

```
$CDTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CDTitle']);
```

Though you should really look in to using PDO and prepared statements. They look a bit intimidating at first, but once you start using them you'll find they aren't much different to work with, but a whole lot more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it like this

```
$CDTitle = $_REQUEST['CDTitle']; // make sure its only an id (SQL Incjection problems)
    $sql = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc, nmc_publisher.pubName
FROM nmc_cd
NATURAL JOIN nmc_category
NATURAL JOIN nmc_publisher
WHERE nmc_cd.CDTitle = '".mysql_real_escape_string($CDTitle)."'
ORDER BY nmc_cd.CDTitle
LIMIT 0 , 30";
```